# How to sort list elements?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort list:

```
["3B", "1A", "2T", "4E", "2A", "4A", "1B", "10E"]
```

to

```
["1B", "1A", "2T", "2A", "3B", "4E", "4A", "10E"]
```

Letters taken form 'BETA'

I tried to use list sort() function, but it not worked in this situation.

Is it possible to make it happen? in for loops?

Comment: You need to make a custom sort key function that compares the numeric portion of the string, and if those are equal, compares the alphabetic portion according to position within the word BETA.

Comment: In Python, sorting accepts a key function, not a less-than function. The key should return values that are themselves ordered the way you want. For you, that could be a tuple consisting of an int with the number, and a second int for the letter indicating its position the the sequence BETA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom `key` to sort your list. First, you want to sort by the number in the string, and then (in case of a tie) sort by the position of the last letter in the word "BETA":

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda s: (int(s[:-1]), "BETA".find(s[-1])))
['1B', '1A', '2T', '2A', '3B', '4E', '4A', '10E']
```